# Is there a term for using different numerical bases on either side of a decimal point?

Tags: terminology

I'm reading through a baseball box score, and it dawned on me that this seems to be essentially what's going on in describing pitching appearances.

For those who are unfamiliar with this, it's common to specify how long a pitcher remained in the game as being x.y innings, where x is the number of full innings and y is the number of outs in the final, partial inning they pitched.  So a starter who is pulled after two outs in the seventh is said to have pitched 6.2 innings.  Obviously, they haven't pitched 6 1/5 innings--they've pitched 6 2/3, since there are only three outs in an inning (there are some unusual "four out" circumstances, but as far as I know they aren't reflected in scorekeeping).

So, in effect, the fractional part of the number is represented in base three, while the integer part is represented in base ten.  Is this something that happens in any other context, and is there a name for it?  Is it even appropriate to call it a "decimal point" in this case--is there a more generic term for that, that includes non-decimal bases?

Comment: Treasury bonds are quoted in $32$nds.  That is, a stated price of, say, $101.03$ means that a $\$100$ face bond will cost $\$101$ plus $\frac 3{32}$ of a dollar.